# input date mm/dd/yy without using scanf function?

Tags: date, get, scanf

As I read, using scanf can cause problems so I want to avoid using it in practice. How else can I take input from user in mm/dd/yy format (which is good practice) ?

Preferably in not too many steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strptime() function , if you first read the string representation into str, you can then use:

```
struct tm tm;
strptime(str, "%m/%d/%Y", &tm);
```

It translates to your date as follows:

```
date.year = tm.tm_year;
date.month = tm.tm_mon;
date.day = tm.tm_mday;
```